# The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt with JDK installed

Tags: python, java

I am trying to run KeplerGL on PyCharm to map some data  and I am getting this error:

The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

I have brew installed the JDK Java and "java -version" outputs the following:

openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.2+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.2+0, mixed mode, sharing)

What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The only `apt` I know is the Linux Advanced Packaging Tool.  Sounds like something's really messed up...like you've somehow installed something meant for a different OS, as seeing `Homebrew` suggests to me that you're on a Mac.  Can you provide more information about the error you're getting?

Comment: Wow.  Everything's great on my Mac, but if I just type "apt" in my console, I get this same error message, and only this error message.  I expect that PyCharm or whatever is indirectly running this binary as well.  So I Googled, and this is indeed a binary that Homebrew manages:  https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/apt.  It's not a name conflict either, because that Brew page agrees that `apt` is the `Advanced Package Tool`.  So I assume that the tool was ported to Mac to support bringing other packages over from Linux to Mac.  But who knows.  Maybe none of this actually helps...sorry about that.